# on your future vs in your future

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between the two sentences below?

- You can expect positive effects on your future.
- You can expect positive effects in your future.

Comment: It is really frustrating when a question is downvoted without an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> You can expect *positive effects on* your future.

If action A has an *effect on your future*, it affects and changes *your future*. Here, "your future" is the *direct object* of the *positive effects*.

> You can expect positive effects *in your future*.

Something happened. That "something" will have some *positive effects* but those *effects* will happen in the future. "In the future" here is just a time clause.

Edit to further clarify:

> Going to college can have positive effects **on** your future.

In the above example, the action of "going to college" can directly affect and change "your future" (the direct object) positively.

> Going to college can have positive effects **in** your future.

In this example, you're saying that the action of "going to college" can have positive effects but you're not saying it will change your future. Rather, "going to college" here affects something, we don't know what *something* is, but the action of "affect" or "have a positive effect" happens later, some time in the future.

......

Comment: I am not able to see any difference in meaning.

Comment: I've edited it. Can you see the difference now?

Comment: I think so. So you're saying that "in your future" = "in the future", given that both mean "a future time" and do not refer to the specific future of the person spoken to?

Comment: "have an effect on something": "something" is affected. "have an effect in the future": the future may not be affected, but some affect will happen in the future.

Comment: I know that, but my example sentence has "in *your* future", not "in the future". What I asked in my last comment is if both mean the same.

Comment: Same thing. You can say the exact same thing with "in your future".

Comment: **In your future** is exceedingly seldom used while **in the future** is common. A Google Books Ngram check shows a virtually imperceptible register of the former and a frequent use of the latter. My advice is to stick to **in the future**.   https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+your+future%2Cin+the+future&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20your%20future%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20future%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cin%20your%20future%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20future%3B%2Cc0

Comment: "on your future" and "on the future" are also different but that's not really the point of this question. It's still nice to know though.

Comment: @RonaldSole That comparison between searches of "in your future" and "in the future" in Google Books is meaningless because the latter is used in used in a lot of contexts which do not refer the future of the receiver, as you can quickly see in the search results. The only relevant results *for this question* are the ones in which "in the future" means "in your future".